# How to make a white section in a design transparent instead of black

Tags: adobe-illustrator

There’s a small white section on a design that I can’t get to turn transparent, it just turns black. How do I fix this problem? [image]

Answer (score 2):

- Select All
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key
- Just tap/click that area...

If it doesn't become transparent, tap/click it again.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to how your project is constructed - It looks to me like there's a black object behind the element you want to remove.

For me, the quickest way to subtract the shape from the background is to open the Pathfinder, select both the shape you want to remove AND the black shape behind it and then select the "Divide" tool in the Pathfinder.

Then you'll likely have to click into the newly-formed group of the objects you had selected and manually delete the shape - then you should be able to see through to the background.